# Torch installation results in not supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

Tried running `pip3 install torch===1.4.0 torchvision===0.5.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html` first, taken from [PyTorch website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)
which resulted in
`No matching distribution found for torch===1.4.0`
 and  `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch===1.4.0 (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)`

Finally downloaded the .whl file from [downloads page](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html) and tried installing locally like so `'C:\Users\Raf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\pip.exe' install torch-1.4.0+cpu-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`
after which I get `torch-1.4.0+cpu-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

using 64 Python 3.8, on 64 bit Windows

Comment: There now is a whl available for cp38-win64

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> using 64 Python 3.8

but you downloaded the `cp37` whl which is for python **3.7**. There is currently no whl file available for python 3.8. So either install from source (probably not recommended), install a different python version or create a virtual environment with python 3.7

**Update**

There is now: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.4.0%2Bcpu-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

Answer (score 3):

I faced the similar issue, even if your python version is correct you can still face this problem if you had install 32x instead of 64x

If it is 32-bit you will face the same problem.
To check the bit version of python on your system run this

```
python -c "import struct;print( 8 * struct.calcsize('P'))"
```

This will return 32 or 64
If it returns 32 change it to 64 and reinstall the PyTorch
https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

Answer (score 0):

work out your version.

python --version

Python 3.10.9

then get the correct version to suit. ie cp310

pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-2.1.0%2Bcpu-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl#sha256=ebba26871b24cb979ed0a24756a773eb6ea04c002b4f71392b50232723d80a6d